# Is there a way to insert an accentuated letter in psql?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm trying to insert an accentuated letter with PostgreSQL (9.6), but I don't manage to do it...

If I copy/paste a query, it removes the accentuated letters, if I try to insert them directly, it does not print anything.

What can I do?

Comment: This is a limitation of your console then, not of `psql`

Comment: save it if file and run `psql -f`. I think it is not postgres, that replaces symbols

Comment: try http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98185/bash-environment-pasting-strings-with-special-characters ?..

Comment: Ok thanks, you can post it as an answer and I will accept it ;)

Comment: It may comes from my console but using pgcli instead of pgsql makes everything work perfectly ;)

Comment: @Simon sorry - did not notice your comment on time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to be shell environment problem, Please try applying solution from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98185/bash-environment-pasting-strings-with-special-characters

`pgcli` I suppose is python and probably has additional libraries