# Can't paste 'π' character into psql query

Tags: postgresql, putty, psql

I'm ssh'd into a redhat appliance using putty and from there I am running psql to query a postgres database. I have validated that my putty, redhat, and psql encoding are all set to utf8.

If I query a record that has π in it results display correctly, including π. I can also paste the character into the putty session and it appears correctly. For example:

```
hostname:~ # π
```

What I cannot do is paste the character into psql. When I try to paste the character nothing happens. Any ideas?

Comment: I've tried to replicate your issue, but the π character worked just fine in psql.

I tried on a locally running version of psql on OSX, and on a remote server after ssh'ing in and running psql remotely.

What version of psql are you running? Have you tried ssh'ing from a different utility?

Comment: `select chr(960)` shows the `π` that you can't copy/paste back?.. I'm quite positive its not psql, but shell or putty

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42899527/5315974 ?..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to insert an accentuated letter in psql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42697964/is-there-a-way-to-insert-an-accentuated-letter-in-psql)

Comment: @Lorenzo: I've tried using both mobaxterm and putty. This is coming from a Windows 7 machine.

Comment: @VaoTsun: I tried adding those 3 lines to inputrc and it did not have an affect. Your query does show the character properly.